# На сколько это по варварски инициализировать переменные в React вот так?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
let mySweetPie;

class MyComponent extends Component{}
  render(){
     mySweetPie = 10;
     return(return smth)
  }
```

Например у меня есть поток данных от родителя к ребенку, и в пропсах лежит переменная, которая нужна извне. Сейчас это выглядит, как брешь в корабле. Есть решения по-лучше?

Comment: очень варварски

Comment: Такое объявление переменных считается нормой только для каких-то констант. Приведите полный пример кода, чтобы можно было посоветовтать как этого избежать

Comment: Использую react dnd, делаю карточки, в которых есть списки, элементы списка можно менять местами. Но нельзя менять местами элементы из разных карточек. В dnd экспортируемый компонент оборачивается в dragsource и в dragtarget. Они требуют первым параметром тип. И  drag и drop элементы будут взаимодействовать между собой только, если у них одинаковый тип. Вот я и хочу задать ID  родительской карточки как тип. Он приходит в пропсах компоненту списка, а задавать его нужно в export defauld dragsource(тип...) (компонент)

Comment: @Jack Всё что Вы написали это конечно хорошо, но можно всё таки код увидеть?

Comment: _И drag и drop элементы будут взаимодействовать между собой только, если у них одинаковый тип._ - почему бы и не задать им одинаковый тип? зачем какая-то переменная?